# Adding content to PivotItem dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a page with a Pivot. It´s based on the Visual Studio Template.

```
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot SelectionChanged="evt_pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <phone:Pivot.Title>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <!-- <TextBlock Text="MyApp" /> -->
                <Image Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" MinWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" Source="/mAppData/logo.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:Pivot.Title>

        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Favoriten">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="13,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,25">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="FELIX ClubRestaurant (Berlin)" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,22" />
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="110" Height="20" Source="/mAppData/stars-3.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="10 min." TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100" Source="http://img.myserver.net/news-teaser//p189j19861b36c5d1pp012i21grgd.gif"/>
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="100" Source="http://img.myserver.net/news-teaser//p187qrndfcj0la0f12clfkv10ec7.gif"/>
                                <Image Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="100" Source="http://img.myserver.net/news-teaser/005e5d03f058fa8f7bd95f6410dfc6d6.gif"/>
                                <Image Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Height="100" Source="http://img.myserver.net/news-teaser/3c05cbf76fba7ada5182b4426e55d96b.gif"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="Empfohlen">
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

I added in CodeBehind the handling for the event SelectionChanged. That works fine. So I can capture by code, when user comes to the second PivotItem.

```
    private async void evt_pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int mPivotIndex = Convert.ToInt16(((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString());
        if (mPivotIndex == 1)
        {
             // HERE I WANT TO INSERT THE SOLUTION
        }
    }
```

Now comes my problem: When user navigates to seconds item, I want to:

- request some data from an WebService (this in not the problem)
- transform the data (this is not the problem) and
- populate the data in a LongListSelector (THIS IS MY PROBLEM PART 1)

In case that an error occures, I want not to display the LongListSelector but a TextBox showing a message (THIS IS MY PROBLEM PART 2)

How can I get my 2 problems get working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind the text/content of your controls in the itemtemplate to the data collection fieldname
Text="{Binding Fieldname}"
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

In your error handling, set the visibility of the Longlistselector to Collapsed.  Then you can show another control which displays the textbox

```
<StackPanel>
<LongListSelector x:Name=”MyListSelector”>
..stuff
</LongListSelector>
<TextBlock x:Name=”MyError” Visibility=”Collapsed”> </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>

Catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MyListSelector.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
MyError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
MyError.Text = Ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the Longlist selector and add the Textbox with the Error message directly from the code behind. see the code below.

```
try
{
   //make the service call and do your stuff
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    MyListSelector.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    var errorTextBox = new TextBox();
    errorTextBox.Text = "some Error has occured";
    //add all the properties you want to add for textbox such as color,height,fontsiz ect..
    //Name your pivotitem control, say pivotitem1
    pivotitem1.Content = errorTextBox;    

}
```

hope this helps.

Note: uncompiled code. pardon compilation errors